# Jquery Plugin not validating a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using Jquery Plugin to validate an Edit form.The validation works fine with the Create Form but it does not work with the Edit form.

My HTML is

```
 <body>
 <div class="container">
 <h1 class="col-sm-offset-2">Edit Provider Details:</h1>
 <br />
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="EditProviderDetailsForm"  method="post">
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">FIRST NAME:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus"    placeholder="Enter the First Name" id="FirstName" data-bind="value:FirstName">
             </div>
      <label class="col-sm-4 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_FirstName">Enter the first name</label>
</div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">CONTACT NUMBER:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-6">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" data- bind="value:ContactNumber" placeholder="Enter the Contact Number"  id="ContactNumber" maxlength="13">
      </div>
         <label class="col-sm-4 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_ContactNum">Enter the Contact Number</label>
     </div>
   <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">EMAIL ADDRESS: </label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" data-    bind="value:ContactEmail" placeholder="Enter your email address"            id="EmailAddress">
        </div>
        <label class="col-sm-4 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_EmailAddress">Enter the Email Address</label>
       </div>
         <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" id="Update" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1 col-       sm-offset-4">Update</button>
        <button type="button" id="Cancel" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-          1">Reset</button>
     </div>
   </form>
  </div>               
    </body>
```

The JavaScript is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("AcceptEmail", function (value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || /^([\w\d\-\.]+)@{1}(([\w\d\-]{1,67})|   ([\w\d\-]+\.[\w\d\-]{1,67}))\.(([a-zA-Z\d]{2,4})(\.[a-zA-Z\d]     {2})?)$/.test(value);
});
 $("#EditProviderDetailsForm").validate({
   onfocusout: function (element, event) {
     this.element(element);
  },
      onkeyup: function (element, event) {
     if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === '') {
         return;
    } else if (element.name in this.submitted) {
    this.element(element);
    }
      },
      rules:
{
    FirstName: { required: true, minlength: 2, maxlength: 20 },
 ContactNumber: { required: true, minlength: 10, maxlength: 10 },
    ContactEmail: { required: true, AcceptEmail: true }
},
       messages: {
      FirstName: {
         required: "Please enter your first name",
        minlength: "Minimum 2 characters required",
            maxlength: "Maximum 20 characters allowed"
    },
        ContactNumber: {
         required: "Please enter your Contact Number",
         minlength: "Enter a 10 digit contact number",
           maxlength: "Enter a 10 digit contact number"
         },
              ContactEmail: {
             required: "Please enter your Email Address",
              AcceptEmail: "Please enter a valid email ID"
          }
       }
    });
 var Provider = {
       SpecializationArray: ko.observableArray(Specialities),
        ProviderID: ko.observable(Edit_data.ProviderID),
        FirstName: ko.observable(Edit_data.FirstName),
      ContactNumber: ko.observable(Edit_data.ContactNumber),
    ContactEmail: ko.observable(Edit_data.ContactEmail)
  }
    ko.applyBindings(Provider);
  });
```

My Scripts are getting loaded in _Layout page in the Shared folder of MVC.

```
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/bootstrap.min.css" />

     <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
     @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")


      <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js">  </script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
        </head>
```

I am at a loss here.Please guide me in the right direction.There are no errors in the Console.

Comment: As far as I can see, there's only 1 form in your code.

Comment: I have not posted the Create from,I just mentioned that its working for the Create from but not working for the Edit form,which I have posted.Both Create and Edit have the same fields

Comment: Do they have the same `id`?

Comment: No,I have made sure they have separate IDs.They are 2 different forms with 2 separate IDs

Comment: I cannot be the only one who has faced this issue with Jquery Plugins.I am truly vexed here.

Comment: You have spaces in your attributes.  Was this an issue with copy and paste, or is it actually like this in your code?  One example: `data- bind`  Another example: `data-    bind="value:ContactEmail"` (there's more visible white space than what the comment shows.

Comment: The is ue got solved but the spaces was a copy/paste issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed one of the basics unfortunately - jQuery Validate requires every input to have a `name` attribute.  Simply copy all your `id` attributes to the `name` and your code will work.

This is described in the [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) for the library.  Also in the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference):

> The name attribute is '''required''' for input elements, the
>   validation plugin doesn't work without it. Usually name and id
>   attributes should have the same value.

Comment: GodDammit!!!!.. How could I do such a silly mistake.I feel really stupid right now.I made the change in my Create form but forgot to do the same in my Edit form.Thanks a lot Ryley.